# XDocument parse method encoding values

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing

I have below code snippet to read file containing xml string and convert it to the XDocument.

```
public static XDocument ReadXmlContent(string xmlFilePath)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(xmlFilePath))
            {
                string content = File.ReadAllText(xmlFilePath);                    
                XDocument xDoc = XDocument.Parse(content);
                return xDoc;
            }
            return null;
        }
```

This is doing my job well but with one issue. 
One of the node in xml string object is

```
<billDescriptionValue>This is the charge in advance for your %quantity% Line isolating unit No. 1A at &#xA3;%quantity rate% per unit per month</billDescriptionValue>
```

now, when i parse this using XDocument.Parse, the above content becomes

`<billDescriptionValue>This is the charge in advance for your %quantity% Line isolating unit No. 1A at £%quantity rate% per unit per month</billDescriptionVa`lue>

so why '& #xA3;' is changed to '£' ?? how can i stop this?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: The xml you received is invalid and has illegal characters.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references

Comment: This is normal behaviour - `XmlReader` will expand entities.  Why is this important?